# Split string using Regex in Postgres function

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, regex-split

I need help splitting the string below using `REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY` in a Postgres function:

```
keyone="valone" key_two="val two" KEY_THREE=val three keyfour="http://sample.domain?par1=val1&par2=val2" keyFIVE=valfive keysix="sample text par1=val6"
```

and the resultant array should look like this:

```
(keyone="valone",key_two="val two",KEY_THREE=val three,keyfour="http://sample.domain?par1=val1&par2=val2",keyFIVE=valfive,keysix="sample text par1=val6")
```

I ended up with this

```
myarray := REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY(mystring, E'\\s(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)');
```

but it is failing to split when value contains space and not enclosed in double quotes (KEY_THREE=val three).

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with postgreSQL so I'm unsure if this would work: `myarray := REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY(mystring, '\s(?=key\w+=)', 'i');`, or if you don't actually got the key-substring in there, then just `\w+=` in the positive lookahead and you can avoid case-insensitive matching then.

Comment: ref: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/AaUfSCvqnU5e8MpD4bv4b/1

Comment: @JvdV this is failing when the value contains a "key=value" syntax. For example: keysix="some text par1=five" How to fix this issue please? Is it possible not to capture keys after odd number of double-quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Write a `FUNCTION`  and then call the function using

```
SELECT split_key_value_pairs('keyone="valone" key_two="val two" KEY_THREE=val three keyfour="http://sample.domain?par1=val1&par2=val2" keyFIVE=valfive');
```

Function here

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_key_value_pairs(input_str text)
    RETURNS text[] AS $$
    DECLARE
        parts text[];
        part text;
        in_quote boolean := false;
        buffer text := '';
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN 1..length(input_str) LOOP
            part := substr(input_str, i, 1);
    
            IF part = '"' THEN
                in_quote := NOT in_quote;
            END IF;
    
            IF part = ' ' AND NOT in_quote THEN
                parts := array_append(parts, buffer);
                buffer := '';
            ELSE
                buffer := buffer || part;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    
        parts := array_append(parts, buffer); -- append last buffer
        RETURN parts;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The Result would be

```
{"keyone="valone"","key_two="val two"",KEY_THREE=val,three,"keyfour="http://sample.domain?par1=val1&par2=val2"",keyFIVE=valfive}
```

Comment: Thank you but this seems not to be working as expected. For example "val three" is split into two objects.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following regular expression **`(\w+)=(?:"([^"]+)"|((?:(?!\s+\w+=).)+))`**.
This expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(           # group and capture to \1:
  \w+       #   word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
)           # end of \1
=           # '='
(?:         # group, but do not capture:
  "         #   '"'
  (         #   group and capture to \2
    [^"]+   #     any character except: '"' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
  )         #   end of \2
  "         #   '"'
 |          # OR
  (         #   group and capture to \3:
    (?:     #     group, but do not capture (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)):
      (?!   #       look ahead to see if there is not:
        \s+ #         whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
        \w+ #         word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))
        =   #         '='
      )     #       end of look-ahead
      .     #       any character except \n
    )+      #     end of grouping
  )         #   end of \3
)           # end of grouping
```

```
select
  array_agg(array[
    grp[1],
    coalesce(grp[2], grp[3])
  ]) as myarray
from regexp_matches('''keyone="valone"
key_two="val two"
KEY_THREE=val three
keyfour="http://sample.domain?par1=val1&par2=val2"
keyFIVE=valfive foo=bar boz-woz''',
      '(\w+)=(?:"([^"]+)"|((?:(?!\s+\w+=).)+))',
      'g') as matches(grp);
```

Results:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| myarray                                                                                                                                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {{keyone,valone},{key_two,"val two"},{KEY_THREE,"val three"},{keyfour,http://sample.domain?par1=val1&par2=val2},{keyFIVE,valfive},{foo,"bar boz-woz'"}} |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Try it on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YhysW4zX).